# Sending Country Code of Visitor from one web Application to another Using .NET (ASP/ MVC )

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am creating an application which tracks user information such as country, city IP of the web site. I send the information about visitors to my second web application which will be updated automatically when a visitor visits my 1st web application which has JavaScripts to track all the information.

Example 
(Application in which Visitor Landed)
. WebPage

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    geoip_country_code() //CountryCode
    geoip_country_name() //CountryName
    geoip_city() //City
</script>
```

(Application in which I will track information about the Visitor)
.WebPage 
?

Please help me through this :S. Will I be using Ajax or something like this which will be giving updates automatically on my second application?

(Programming Language C# is prefered)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach

Instead of making cross domain calls between two applications via Ajax,

- you can write a simple web service on your web application 2,
- make an ajax call to your webapplication 1
- web application 1 calls the service on webapplication 2 to update the
  data from server side